# Connection refused error when using sockets between C# (server) and Java (Client) applications

Tags: java, c#, sockets, client-server

I am trying to create a socket connection between a .Net server application and Java Client Application.
I am getting an error from the java client application:

> Connection refused: connect

Notes:

1. Communicating with a .Net Client Application, works fine.
2. I have disables the windows firewall
3. Undoubtedly, I am running the server application in the background and then I am running the client application

Following are my server code (C#):

```
public class Server
{
    public Server()
    {
        CreateListener();
    }

    public void CreateListener()
    {
        // Create an instance of the TcpListener class.
        TcpListener tcpListener = null;
        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];

        string output;
        try
        {
            // Set the listener on the local IP address
            // and specify the port.
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 13);
            tcpListener.Start();
            output = "Waiting for a connection...";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            output = "Error: " + e.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(output);
        }           
    }
}
```

and client application code (Java):

```
public class smtpClient {

    public void Send() {
        Socket smtpSocket = null;  
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;
        try {

            smtpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 13); // FAILURE

            os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It fails at the following line in the Java Client Application:

```
smtpSocket = new Socket("localhost", 13);
```

Comment: e.stackTrace looks not very helpful: #172(length=0)

Comment: This is the value I am getting when asking for e.stackTrace in the last catch (IOException e)

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1 in your client. If this works, you will need a localhost entry in your hosts file.

Comment: Make the listener :  tpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 10013);  then client : smtpSocket = new Socket("192.x.x.x", 10013); Make IP the actual IP of PC.

Comment: @jr593, yes already tried but it doesn't work as well

Comment: @YvetteColomb, there is no such method e.GetType().Name

Comment: @jdweng, just changing to IPAddress.Any make it works

Comment: @YvetteColomb, the error comes from Java not from C#. e is from catch in the java code, please see my post. Thanks

Comment: The code I posted would of worked in any situation.  There is a Host file on the PC and depending on the data in the file the code you were using may failed.  So I changed the client just in case the host file contained 127.0.0.1 as first entry.  I also changed the port number just in case a firewall or virus checker was blocking port 13.

Comment: I am aware of the existence of the host file but sorry I am not clear with your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what is the issue you are facing, but you need to start with a solid foundation to discover these issues.

As a rule of thumb, you should always write one piece (typically the server) first and verify connectivity (say using telnet) and then write the other piece (typically client)  and verify its connectivity.

I always keep a Standard Client and Server handy to test whether its my code or its the environment/configuration.

Below is a sample code that works fine to test connectivity.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

class ClientServer {
    static void Main() {
        new Thread(() => { StartServer("localhost", 5013); }).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to start the client...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        StartClient("localhost", 5013);
    }

    public static void StartServer(string serverInterface, int port) {
        try {
            IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(serverInterface);
            string hostName = hostInfo.HostName;
            IPAddress ipAddress = hostInfo.AddressList[0];
            var server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for a connection at {server.LocalEndpoint}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ctrl+c to exit server...");
            while (true) {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine($"Server says - Client connected: {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {
                    using (var _client = (TcpClient)state)
                    using (NetworkStream stream = _client.GetStream()) {
                        string msg = stream.ReadAsciiData();
                        if (msg == "Hello!") {
                            stream.WriteAsciiData($"Time:{DateTime.Now: yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm zzz}. Server name is {hostName}");
                        }
                    }

                }, client);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public static void StartClient(string serverInterface, int port) {
        Console.WriteLine("Client started...");
        try {
            using (var client = new TcpClient(serverInterface, port))
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Client says - Hello!");
                stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello!"));
                string msg = stream.ReadAsciiData();
                Console.WriteLine($"Client says - Message from server: Server@{client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}: {msg}");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Client exited");
    }


}

static class Utils {
    public static void WriteAsciiData(this NetworkStream stream, string data) {
        stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
    }
    public static string ReadAsciiData(this NetworkStream stream) {
        var buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    public static void Write(this NetworkStream stream, byte[] data) {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Now to your specific problem,

1. The choice of port 13, is not ideal for testing. Usually all ports below 1024 are considered privileged. i.e. a firewall or antivirus might block your attempt to listen on that port
2. Remember that IPV6 addresses plays a role. Your machine might have that enabled or disabled based on your configuration. You want to make sure that if your server is listening on a IPv6 interface, then your client also connects on the same
3. Which brings us to another related point: Irrespective of you are using IPv6 interface or not, the client needs to connect to the same interface the server is listening on. This might seem obvious, but is often missed. A typical machine 
   has at-least 2 interfaces: One for localhost (127.*.*.* called loopback interface) and another non local (typically 10.*.*.* or 192.*.*.*, but not restricted to it). It can so happen (especially when you pick the first available interface to bind your server without knowing which one it is) that server might be listening on non loopback interface like say 192.168.1.10 interface and the client might be connecting to 127.0.0.1, and you can see why the client will get "connection refused" errors

The sample code above works and you can test your code with it. You can us telnet for a client or just my sample code. You can play around changing the `serverInterface` values to some surprising discoveries which are accentuated by 
`ipAddress = hostInfo.AddressList[0]` line

Hope this helps you with your debugging

Comment: I am getting a compiling error saying that ReadAsciiData is not a method of NetworkStream.

Comment: Did you copy the `Utils` class?

Comment: Oh, I missed the extension methods, my bad :-(